# How to get the text from a matched view using Detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

I want to test a view that has a list and filtering functionality:

1. I want to check the text of the first row and save it
2. Filter using that text
3. Check again that the same element is rendered

Thing is, when I match and element using `element(by.id('some-id'))`, how can I retrieve info from that element (if it is possible) like the text it contains?

Comment: If your component is a `Text` component, you can use `expect(element(by.id('some-id'))).toHaveText('Welcome to React Native!')`

Comment: But what if I do not know the text that is going to be in there?

Comment: This feature is not yet supported, it's a good extension of the API, PRs are very welcome!

Comment: @FerranNegre "But what if I do not know the text that is going to be in there?" - always good to try and keep your tests deterministic.

Comment: Oh no, I wish this feature was supported :( I'm trying to use detox to run automated benchmarks and now I'm stuck at the final part, that is getting the benchmark result from the screen.

Comment: Opened an issue for this: https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/445

Answer (score 6):

I created the [detox-getprops](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detox-getprops) npm package incorporating the hack mentioned by Maxime Helen. It allows retrieving the text and some other (platform-dependent) properties of the element.

```
const { getText } = require('detox-getprops');

const text = await getText(element(by.id('heading')));
expect(text).toEqual('Step One');
```

I hope [Detox #445](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/445) will be resolved soon after which this package can be deprecated.

**Update:** You can now fetch the text on iOS using the [getAttributes](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/DetoxNext/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#getAttributes--ios-only) method. The detox-getprops library is still needed for Android (tracked using [Detox #2083](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2083)).

Comment: is this package being maintained ?

Answer (score 4):

Hacky/funny workaround elaborated from this [comment](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/445#issuecomment-477488397):

```js
const readVisibleText = async (testID) => {
  try {
    await expect(element(by.id(testID))).toHaveText('_unfoundable_text');
    throw 'We never should get here unless target element has unfoundable text';
  } catch (error) {
    if (device.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
      const start = `accessibilityLabel was "`;
      const end = '" on ';
      const errorMessage = error.message.toString();
      const [, restMessage] = errorMessage.split(start);
      const [label] = restMessage.split(end);
      return label;
    } else {
      // Android to be tested
      const start = 'Got:';
      const end = '}"';
      const errorMessage = error.message.toString();
      const [, restMessage] = errorMessage.split(start);
      const [label] = restMessage.split(end);
      const value = label.split(',');
      var combineText = value.find(i => i.includes('text=')).trim();
      const [, elementText] = combineText.split('=');
      return elementText;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported, the progress is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/445).